# Chain tasks using continuation task

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I'm trying to chain tasks, so as soon as the one finishes the next starts, but the UI doesn't update. I did a course in react and the one lesson is where you update the UI based on state changes in the application, and that is what I'm trying to replicate. Change the state of the application (basically I'll be running methods that run return a bool for validation), and then update the UI accordingly, I'm also using binding, but for some reason its not running as intended, I don't know if I follow the documentation incorrectly. What can I change or fix to make this work and is it practically correct to use more than one task in a single `async Task<T>` method

```
public async Task<string> Connect_To_Ip()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        details.State = "Connection To IP 127.0.01.258.....";
        Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
        }).ContinueWith(result => new Task(async () =>
        {
           await Task.Run(() =>
           {
               if (result.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
               {
                  details.State = "Validating Card Number......";
                }                    
           });  
              
        }), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

     return details.State;
}
```

How I'm calling the original task

```
Task connect = Connect_To_Ip();
await connect;
```

Comment: You should probably read up on what `await` does and what `Task.Run` does.  Note that you are starting up two threads in that code.  Also note that `await` will wrap all the code after the await statement into a continuation and execute it when the awaited task is complete.  I think if you just ran `await SomethingTasky(); DoSomethingNonTasky(); await SomethingElseTasky(); FinallyDoNonTaskyStuff();` you'd get the behavior you want (sorry, I can't quite figure out what you are trying to do).

Comment: Basically when one task completes what I want to do is change the text of ``details.State`` and the UI will show the updated value until all tasks are completed

Comment: Why are you creating background threads? Are they necessary? Don't ever use Task.Wait. Instead await the Task: `await Task.Delay()`. Since you are using await, you don't need ContinueWith. In case modifying details.State is modifying UI, you will have to modify details.State  from the Dispatcher.

Comment: @BionicCode I want validation for input fields to run in the background while simultaneously showing the current state of the validation meaning ``details.State`` will change based on what validation is being performed, and I want to keep the UI responsive

Comment: Once upon a time there was no `await`, so developers had to work with `ContinueWith` continuations, and ended-up with spaghetti code. Then the `await` was invented, and everyone was delighted that the spaghetti code days had gone forever. And then came your question, showing that `await` can be combined with `ContinueWith`, and produce the spaghetti-est code the world has ever seen!

Comment: @PureWare -Legends Of Gaming, may I suggest you to try event-based approach? You can do different work asynchroniously and get notifications from events with some result. You not need continuations, you just call what you need when it should be called. Check this "little" example, maybe it help you with some ideas: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zQhGTK.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you for your inspiring words of wisdom or the lack there of, this is my first attempt at trying this and I did not understand what was happening, but thank you for your words

Comment: PureWare just to clarify: I am not accusing you for being a bad coder. I have coded myself more horrible things in the past, and I might do it again in the future. Your question is clearly motivated by a desire to learn and improve. My point is that when people see painfully bad code, they might vote instinctively based on the code they see, and not based on the intentions of the poster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `await` then you don't need `Task.ContinueWith`. Everything that follows the awaited operation is a continuation. Since you want to validate on a background thread, you must post the changes back to the UI thread in order to update the UI elements, otherwise you will produce cross-thread exceptions.
This is because UI elements can't be updated from a background thread, except the update occurs via `INotifyPropertyChanged` and data binding.
One way to do this is to use the `Dispatcher` to invoke UI manipulations on the UI thread or use the `Progress<T>` class, which will always execute the registered callback on the UI thread.

Your fixed and simplified code could look like this example:

```
public async Task ValidateAsync()
{
  // Register the callback that updates the UI with the 'progressReporter'.
  // Progress<T> must be instantiated on the UI thread it is associated with
  var progressReporter = new Progress<string>(message => details.State = message);

  // Execute the operation on a background thread
  await Task.Run(() => ConnectToIp(progressReporter));

  // Continuation starts here, after await
}

public async Task ConnectToIp(IProgress<string> progressReporter)
{
  progressReporter.Report("Connection To IP 127.0.01.258.....");

  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

  // Continuation starts here, after await

  progressReporter.Report("Validating Card Number......");
}
```

It is recommended to use async APIs when possible instead of using background threads. For example, to connect to a server without blocking the UI you can use

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
```

Many IO classes provide an async API.

Furthermore, I recommend to take a look at the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface. It is the recommended way to implement property validation and allows to provide UI error feedback in a very easy way.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in Windows Forms (I had a test Windows Forms project open), but it should be about the same in WPF.  I dropped a button, a label and a text box on the form.  Then I wrote this code:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await ValidateTextBox();
    if (result != null)
    {
        label1.Text = result;
        return;
    }
    var intResult = await ReadTextBox();
    label1.Text = intResult.ToString();
    await IncrementTextBox();
    intResult = await ReadTextBox();
    label1.Text = intResult.ToString();
}

private async Task<string> ValidateTextBox()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out _)) {
        return "Not Valid";
    }
    //otherwise
    return null;
}

private async Task<int> ReadTextBox()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out var result))
    {
        throw new Exception("Don't do that");
    }
    return result;
}

private async Task IncrementTextBox()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out var result))
    {
        throw new Exception("Don't do that");
    }
    textBox1.Text = (result + 1).ToString();
}
```

If you type something that's not an `int` into the text box and press the button, a few seconds go by, and then `Not Valid` shows up in the label.

If there is a number there, then there is a pause and the number shows up in the label. Then another pause and the text box number will increment by 1. Finally after another pause, the label will show the incremented value.

Note that this all runs on a single thread. But, in spite of all the delays, the UI remains responsive the whole time.

Put breakpoints at the start of each function and on the lines after each of the awaits in the button click handler. Step through (not into) the whole thing and you'll see how the awaits create continuations